# What are native transport requests in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

When looking at node details in Datastax OpsCenter:

[image]

We can see that there were 34903422 "native-transport-requests", but 1072 were blocked.

- Could someone explain what is native transport request? What is that in relation to mutation?
- Is it normal that they are being blocked and what does it mean?

BTW. We can also see that there were 93 mutations dropped and we know what that means: [What is mutation in cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573106/what-is-mutation-in-cassandra).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native transport is the CQL Native Protocol (as opposed to the Thrift Protocol) and is the way all modern Cassandra Driver's communicate with the server. This includes all reads/writes/schemachanges/etc ...

A blocked request is one that is sitting around waiting for something else to complete before it can run. Very few C* operations are actually blocking so the total blocked number should be very low. The total count is just the over time sum of all requests that were blocked.

Comment: If `Native-Transport-Requests` include reads, what is the difference to pending ReadRequests (from `nodetool tpstats`)?